# C# minmax graph search

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, tree-traversal, traveling-salesman, graph-traversal

EDIT 3:
Okay, so i got my code to work, but i'm facing a huge memory consumption problem if i'm using let's say 16 nodes and a search depth above 11.

an soemone check the code and tell me how can i correct that memory leak?

Here's the full code:

```
public void searchTSP(
    int depth,
    RouterPoint startpoint,
    bool isRound,
    IRouter<RouterPoint> router)
{
  #region TSP_startpointCheck
  if (!routepoints[0].Location.Equals(startpoint.Location))
  {
    int index = Array
      .FindIndex(routepoints, x => x.Location == startpoint.Location);

    if (index != -1 && index != 0) //it's somewhere in the array
    {
      RouterPoint temprp = routepoints[0];
      routepoints[0] = routepoints[index]; //put it to index 0
      routepoints[index] = temprp;
    }
    else //it's not in the array
    {
      //we add it...
      RouterPoint[] ta = new RouterPoint[routepoints.Length + 1];
      routepoints.CopyTo(ta, 0);
      ta[routepoints.Length] = startpoint;
      ta.CopyTo(routepoints, 0);
    }
  }
  #endregion

  selectedRouter = router;
  if (pathDictionary == null)
  {
    pathDictionary = new Dictionary<int[], double>(new IntArrayComparer());
    fillDictionary();
  }            

  DecisionPath bestPath = new DecisionPath();
  //DecisionPath currentPath = new DecisionPath();
  //List<DecisionPath> listOfPaths = new List<DecisionPath>();
  //List<int> visited = new List<int>();
  //List<RouterPoint> waypoints = routepoints.ToList();

  DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
  RouteNode root = new RouteNode();
  root.parent = null;
  root.curr = 0;
  root.weight = 0.0f;
  root.isTerminal = false;
  root.memory = new List<short>();
  root.memory.Add(root.curr);
  calculateChildren(root);

  double bestval=double.MaxValue;
  while (bestPath.list.Count < routepoints.GetLength(0))
  {
    bestval = double.MaxValue;
    int bestIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < root.children.Count; i++)
    {
      RouteNode child = root.children[i];
      double t = minimax(child, depth);
      if (t < bestval)
      {
        bestval = t;
        bestIndex = i;
        bestPath.cost = bestval;
        bestPath.list = child.memory;
      }
    }

    RouteNode temp = root.children[bestIndex];
    root.children.Clear();
    root.children.Add(temp);
    root = root.children[0];
  }

  //My result is in the bestPath class 
  // which has two properties: a list of indexes
  // representing my found result node sequence
  // and a double containing the total cost of the path
}

class RouteNode
{
  public RouteNode parent { get; set; }
  public short curr { get; set; }
  public bool isTerminal { get; set; }
  public float weight { get; set; }
  public List<RouteNode> children { get; set; }
  public List<short> memory { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// List of all children of a node that should be removed
/// </summary>
private List<RouteNode> killList;

/// <summary>
/// MiniMax recursive search for deciding witch ode to go to
/// </summary>
/// <param name="point">Input node</param>
/// <param name="depth">How deep will we search</param>
/// <returns>Weight value</returns>
private double minimax(RouteNode point, int depth)
{
  if (point.isTerminal || depth <= 0)
  {
    //if (point.isTerminal)
    if (point.weight < bestyVal)
    {
      bestyVal = point.weight;
      //Console.WriteLine(
      //    "{0} - {1}",
      //    string.Join(", ", point.memory.ToArray()),
      //    point.weight.ToString());
    }

    return point.weight;
  }

  double alpha = double.PositiveInfinity;
  if (point.children == null || point.children.Count == 0 )
    calculateChildren(point);

  killList = new List<RouteNode>();
  for (int i=0; i< point.children.Count; i++)
  {
    RouteNode child = point.children[i];
    if (child != null)
    {
      if (!child.isTerminal && child.weight > bestyVal)
      {
        child = null;
        continue;
      }

      alpha = Math.Min(alpha, minimax(child, depth - 1));
    }
    else
      continue;
  }

  point.children.RemoveAll( e => killList.Contains(e));
  //killList = null;
    return alpha;
}

/// <summary>
/// Calculates possible children for a node
/// </summary>
/// <param name="node">Input node</param>
private void calculateChildren(RouteNode node)
{
  int c = node.curr;
  List<int> possibleIndexes = Enumerable
      .Range(0, routepoints.GetLength(0))
      .ToList();

  RouteNode curNod = node;

  if (node.children == null)
    node.children = new List<RouteNode>();

  while (curNod != null)
  {
    possibleIndexes.Remove(curNod.curr);
    curNod = curNod.parent;
  }
  //imamo še neobiskane potomce...
  foreach (int i in possibleIndexes)
  {
    RouteNode cc = new RouteNode();
    cc.curr = (short)i;
    cc.parent = node;
    double temp=0.0;
    if (!pathDictionary.TryGetValue(new int[] { node.curr, i }, out temp))
    {
      //preracunajPoti(node.curr, i, selectedRouter);
      throw new Exception(
          String.Format(
              "Missed a path? {0} - {1}",
              node.curr,
              i));
    }

    cc.weight = cc.parent.weight + (float)temp;
    cc.memory = node.memory.ToList();
    cc.memory.Add(cc.curr);

    if (possibleIndexes.Count == 1)
      cc.isTerminal = true;
    else
      cc.isTerminal = false;

    node.children.Add(cc);
  }
  //jih dodamo
  possibleIndexes = null;    
}
```

Comment: Is it really a leak, or just high memory consumption?

Comment: I don't believe consuming 6GB of RAM can be considered high memory consumption at 16 nodes, depth limit 13... I beleive it's a leak somewhere...

Comment: 16 nodes at each depth?

Comment: Overall 16 nodes, each connected to every other. The depth is the max depth where we look at from the current node and by gettingthe best value we decide on the next node.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `(16**13)` is way over 6GB.

Comment: That would be true, if i wouldn't remove the nodes, that were not selected, yet I try(?) to do that to conserve memory space.

Comment: even if you trim 99.9% of the nodes, (16**13) * 0.001 is 4.5 trillion nodes. Even if your nodes are 1 byte that is a huge memory impact

Comment: The `Dictionary<int[], double>` can bloat up quickly, especially when you have a big array.

Comment: Yes, but that dictionary is N*N, which in my case is 16*16 meaning 256 entries only... I use it to save weights or distances between RouterPoints

Comment: hey @mao47 if you're up here in the next hour write that as an Anwser so i can give you the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing in my two cents on this, @mao47 is dead on, in that there is not a memory leak just a massive amount of memory needed.

I came across this thread when looking for reading on MinMax searching and it is worth adding there is a fair bit of work out there on optimizing MinMax and other algorithms. I found **[this](http://people.csail.mit.edu/plaat/tr9418.ps.gz)** paper useful reading for example (language was reasonably understandable given my personal rate of academic decay and time t since I finished school).